# Redirect to different page if user account is not activated

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, activation

A snip of code

```
$LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT user_handle, user_password FROM users_entity WHERE user_handle=%s AND user_password=%s AND activation_status='Active'",
    GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "text"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text")); 

  $LoginRS = mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $f12_database_connect) or die(mysql_error());
  $loginFoundUser = mysql_num_rows($LoginRS);
  if ($loginFoundUser) {
     $loginStrGroup = "";


    //declare two session variables and assign them
    $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
    $_SESSION['logged_in']="True";
    $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;       

    if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && true) {
      $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];  
    }
    header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
  }
  else {
    header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
  }
}
```

The database queries users that are `activation_status="Active"`. That field has either of the two values which are `"Pending"` or `"Active"`. I want to send to another page if the status is `"Pending"`. The page would be for users that haven't activated their account. How do grab that result and assign it to a variable? Or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just select the data without referring to the activation_status and check it with an if statement.

EDIT:

The code you are probably looking for:

```
$LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT user_handle, user_password, activation_status FROM users_entity WHERE user_handle=%s AND user_password=%s",
    GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "text"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text")); 

  $LoginRS = mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $f12_database_connect) or die(mysql_error());
  $loginFoundUser = mysql_num_rows($LoginRS);
  if ($loginFoundUser) {
    // Make sure user is activated.
    $row = mysql_fetch_Array($LoginRS);
    if ($row['activation_status'] === 'Pending') {
      header("Location: some-other-page");
    }

    $loginStrGroup = "";


    //declare two session variables and assign them
    $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
    $_SESSION['logged_in']="True";
    $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;       

    if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && true) {
      $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];  
    }
    header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
  }
  else {
    header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
  }
}
```

Comment: How do I check it with an if statement. Would it be if(loginFoundUser['activation_status'])? How do I pick that column for my if statement?

Answer (score -1):

This is the solution and **proper coding**...

```
<?php
$LoginRS_StrQuery   =   'SELECT user_handle, user_password, activation_status FROM users_entity '.
                        "WHERE user_handle=%s AND user_password=%s LIMIT 0,1";
$LoginRS__query     =   sprintf($LoginRS_StrQuery, GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "text"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text"));
$LoginRS            =   mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $f12_database_connect);
if(is_resource($LoginRS) && mysql_num_rows($LoginRS) > 0){
    $loginStrGroup  =   '';

    //declare two session variables and assign them
    $_SESSION['MM_Username']    =   $loginUsername;
    $_SESSION['logged_in']      =   'True';
    $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup']   =   $loginStrGroup;

    $LoggedUser     =   mysql_fetch_assoc($LoginRS);
    if($LoggedUser['activation_status'] === 'Pending'){
        // redirect him/her to wherever you want
    } elseif(isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && true){
        $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];
        exit;
    } else{
        header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
        exit;
    }
} else{
    header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: If I wanted it to redirect to a different page for ='Pending' would I just replace that for 'Active'?

Comment: `$_SESSION['logged_in'] = 'True';`, `isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && true` you call that proper coding? -1

Comment: @atno: I call that proper coding up to his standards. If I changed those, who knows what sky would fall above us. He might be checking elsewhere with `if($_SESSION['logged_in'] === 'True')`, if I changed that all his authentication would go south. Also, `&& true`, he might have used that for testing or whatever... So, take into account the context before you down vote.

Comment: @Kevin Oluseun Karimu: Yes, you just change it to `Pending`. I updated the code for you. There is an unnecessary `&& true` forced condition on this line `elseif(isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && true)`. So make sure you remove `&& true`, if you did not add it there intentionally.